# How do Items like "Spines of Seething Hatred" affect the type of a a spell?

Tags: diablo-iii

Okay,at first:question title might be confusing so if anyone got a better idea,please edit it :)

In Diablo,there are different kind of spells.Primary spells seem to be all spells that are per standard bound to left click.However there is another categorie I am not sure of what it does actually mean:(Hatred) Spenders and (hatred) generators.

I want to ask my question by using an example:

Let's say I have equipped the legendary Quiver [Spines of Seething Hatred](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/spines-of-seething-hatred) and I've got the full [Marauders Set](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/marauders-carapace).Would my Sentries still shoot Chakrams(because they don't spend any hatred now)?Would Chakram be affected by items that increase the damage of Ressource generators(like the [new Marauders 2 Setbonus](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/blog/16802653/patch-212-ptr-patch-notes-19-11-2014)*)?

> - *"(2) Set Bonus
>     Now increases the damage of your Hatred generators by 40% for every Sentry you have active"

Comment: For now in the PTR, the bonus (2) of the Marauder set indicates that you gain +40% from generators aswell as 40% bonus for Impale, Chakram, Elmental Arrow,  Cluster Arrow and Multishot (http://imgur.com/QgZHpeV). Plus if you read the patch note : *The following changes are not intended to be a nerf to Demon Hunters or the Embodiment of the Marauder set and additional tuning may be necessary*. So as long as the PTR is not over we won't know for sure what's intended. I'd call a close vote as off topic (unreleased content) but boutied question can not be closed.

Comment: This questions was not specifically about the marauders set. It was about the question wether spells like cha kram would change from hatred spender to hatred generator by items

Comment: My bad I misread the second part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no way to verify this personally (so, grain of salt, et cetera), but the Diablo Wiki [says this about the Spines of Seething Hatred](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Spines_of_Seething_Hatred):

> The unique affix turns Chakram into Hatred generator: instead of spending Hatred, it generates one. **However, for all purposes, it still counts as secondary, Hatred-spending skill.**

Assuming this information is accurate, what I'm interpreting that to mean is that, for your purposes, Chakram would still be considered a "Hatred spender" regardless of the fact that it actually generates Hatred when used with the quiver.

So, in the context of the Marauder's 6-piece set bonus, your Sentries would still fire Chakrams. Likewise, it would follow that the new 2-piece bonus would not apply to Chakram, since it's still classified as a "Hatred spender" despite the added effect from the quiver.