# Marauder's Set: what counts as a hatred spender or generator?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

I have the 4-piece bonus of the Marauder's Set, but not the 6-piece yet. I also have the Spines of Seething Hatred, which means that my Chakram generates hatred, rather than spending it.

I'm having trouble understanding the 4-piece bonus,

> Sentries cast your Hatred spender when you do.

It seems to work fine with Multi-shot, so I assume I'm not confusing the meanings of 'spender' and 'generator'; I use Multi-shot and three more spray out from my sentries. But Rapid Fire, with the Bombardment rune, doesn't appear to work (ie. I don't see my sentries dropping a stream of grenades, or even any grenades), whereas it *does* work with Chakram (I use it with Twin Chakram, and my sentries cover the screen with them). I thought this was pretty weird, because the 6-piece bonus specifically declares Chakram as one of my generators.

So, (a) does this just mean the Chakram is covered by both set bonuses (ie. it's a spender *and* generator of hatred), and (b) does the 4-piece bonus work with Rapid Fire, and if so, why can't I see it working?

**EDIT:** [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192291/how-do-items-like-spines-of-seething-hatred-affect-the-type-of-a-a-spell/192559#192559) argues that Chakram would be considered a spender but not a generator. But as far as I can see, I seem to be able to have my cake and eat it too, if the 6-piece bonus text and my experience are both accurate:

> Your generators, Elemental Arrow, Chakram, Impale, Multishot, and
>   Cluster Arrow deal 100% increased damage for every active sentry.

I'll also keep this question open because I'm still confused about how Rapid Fire works with this.

Comment: Rapid Fire *doesn't* work with Sentries because it's a channelled ability - Sentries won't cast any channelled abilities.

Comment: By channelled ability, you mean one with an initial resource cost and then an ongoing one as I continue to use it? Thanks :) Happy to accept this, @JonK!

Comment: The 6-bonus isn't declaring chakram or any of those spells as generators. It increases the bonuses of all generators (primary skills) _and_ those named skills.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification re. the 6-piece bonus, @VanBuzzKill! Send painfully obvious in hindsight. My high school English teachers should be disappointed ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rapid Fire is a channelled ability, that is, you're continually paying Hatred to keep it active. Sentry Turrets *will not* use any channelled abilities, only ones with the full Hatred cost paid up front in full. Certain other Hatred spenders (such as Sentry Turret itself - imagine how broken that would be!) are also excluded for various reasons.

Also, even with the Spines of Seething Hatred equipped, Chakram *does* still count as a Hatred spender. The same is true of Elemental Arrow with Kridershot equipped.

Comment: Chakram always counts as a hatred spender, no matter if you have SoSH equipped or not. Same goes for elemental arrow with Kridershot.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill Useful to know, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 1):

Marauder's 4-piece bonus is worded pretty vaguely, as in fact it only includes 5 of 8 skills that spend Hatred (well, 7 if we exclude Sentry itself :-)

One way to rationalize this is to exclude channeled spells (Rapid Fire and Strafe) as @JonK suggests.

Another is to just consider the *list of spenders in 6-piece bonus* - Elemental Arrow, Chakram, Impale, Multishot, and Cluster Arrow are exactly what 4-piece bonus encompasses.